# botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound - Pass AWS credentials to docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-credentials

This seems to be an issue many people have faced but the solutions I tried haven't solved it:

I have a python app that I dockerized and that I want to push to an EC2 container, however, once dockerized, the app has issues (locally) to access my AWS credentials:

```
santeau_session = boto3.Session(profile_name='Santeau')
db = santeau_session.resource('dynamodb',  region_name='us-west-2')
MainPage = db.Table('mp')
```

When trying to pass them that way:`docker run -v $HOME/.aws/credentials:/home/app/.aws/credentials:ro ks/mz`
I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "./main.py", line 17, in <module>
    santeau_session = boto3.Session(profile_name='Santeau')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 80, in __init__
    self._setup_loader()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 120, in _setup_loader
    self._loader = self._session.get_component('data_loader')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 698, in get_component
    return self._components.get_component(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 937, in get_component
    self._components[name] = factory()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 158, in <lambda>
    lambda:  create_loader(self.get_config_variable('data_path')))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 251, in get_config_variable
    return self.get_component('config_store').get_config_variable(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 313, in get_config_variable
    return provider.provide()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 410, in provide
    value = provider.provide()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 471, in provide
    scoped_config = self._session.get_scoped_config()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 351, in get_scoped_config
    raise ProfileNotFound(profile=profile_name)
botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (Santeau) could not be found
```

My credentials file looks (kind of) like this, and the app correctly connects when not run with docker:

```
aws_access_key_id = ------------------
aws_secret_access_key = ------------------
[Santeau]
aws_access_key_id = ------------------
aws_secret_access_key = ------------------
```

Why does it work undockerized but not dockerized, and how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your docker container isn't running as the user and with the home you're expecting.  I noticed that you hard coded `/home/app/.aws/credentials`

You should login to your container and discover what user it's running as and where your home is.  You could run `aws configure` and then find where the credentials files were stored.

Many run as root so your command would look something like this `docker run -v ~/.aws/:/root/.aws:ro your_image`

Edit:  Alternatively, you can pass the AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE environment variable of your file location directly.  Here's more information:  https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/guide/configuration.html

Comment: 'docker run -v ~/.aws/:/root/.aws:ro your_image' worked, thanks