# Problems with mounting .aws credentials directory inside a docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, macos, boto3, minikube

I have the following docker compose:

```
services:
  run_program:
    image: image:1
    entrypoint: python main.py
    environment:
      - HOME=/home
    volumes:
      - $HOME/.aws:/home/.aws:ro
```

This should allow me to access host `~/.aws/credentials` inside docker. However `boto3` is spitting this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (default) could not be found
```

When I open an interactive docker session on that image like so:

```
docker run -e "HOME=/home" -v $HOME/.aws:/home/.aws -it --entrypoint bash image:1
```

And I check what is inside `/home/.aws` I see a credentials file there. But when I try to do `cat /home/.aws/credentials` to check the contents I get:

```
cat: /home/.aws/credentials: Is a directory
```

And the directory is empty.
According to all tutorials and documentations this should work. All files inside host `~/.aws` have read permissions and `~/.aws/credentials` on host have the `default` profile set up.

If it makes any difference my host machine is a Mac, and docker daemon is provided by minikube.

UPDATE:

After some more digging I see I should first mount the host directory in minikube VMlike this:

```
minikube mount ~/.aws/:/host/.aws
```

but trying this gives the following error:

```
Exiting due to GUEST_MOUNT: mount with cmd /bin/bash -c "sudo mount -t 9p -o dfltgid=$(grep ^docker: /etc/group | cut -d: -f3),dfltuid=$(id -u docker),msize=262144,port=55424,trans=tcp,version=9p2000.L 192.168.64.1 /host/.aws" : /bin/bash -c "sudo mount -t 9p -o dfltgid=$(grep ^docker: /etc/group | cut -d: -f3),dfltuid=$(id -u docker),msize=262144,port=55424,trans=tcp,version=9p2000.L 192.168.64.1 /host/.aws": Process exited with status 32
stdout:

stderr:
mount: /host/.aws: mount(2) system call failed: Connection refused.
```

And this seems to be related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171915/minikube-mount2-system-call-failed-connection-refused) however I haven't figured it out how to solve this on a Mac yet.

Comment: Do you know which minikube driver you're using?  It looks like the [filesystem mount paths](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/) could be different depending on the driver.

Comment: I am using hyperkit. And yes after some more digging I see I need to mount in minikube first and then in docker . But I am getting  mount(2) system call failed: Connection refused. Error when I try to mount in minikube VM. Will eddit question to include this.

Comment: There is a typo in `$HOME/.aws:/home/.aws:ro`, should be something like `$HOME/.aws:/home/ubuntu/.aws:ro`

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67521601/botocore-exceptions-profilenotfound-pass-aws-credentials-to-docker-image ?

Comment: Not really, the issue is generalised for mounting any host directory to a docker container running behind minikube. I can't mount any host directory.

Comment: Currently I will bypass this issue by providing credentials as env variables, but will circle back to this mounting problem and I hope I find what the problem is.